# TeX Studio doesn't recognize certain amsmath commands even after loading packages

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

Here is my code:

[image: code screenshot]

As you can see, TeX Studio doesn't recognize the `proof` environment. Nonetheless, I *have* activated the `amsmath` package in the preferences:

[image: preferences screenshot]

So why isn't it working? I have tried restarting the PC to see if it would load the package but it didn't work.

I am using the ProTeXt packages. The output file looks fine.

Comment: `amsmath` doesn't deal with theorem-like environments, that is what `amsthm` does. Try activating the `cwl` for `amsthm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Did that, but still marks the syntax as incorrect. I've also added a \usepackage{asmthm} command at the beginning.

Comment: You had `\usepackage{amsthm}` already, no need for more than one. But I think I realized your mistake. The `proof` environment itself is recognized (not highlighted in red), but the thing is that it is *not* a math environment. To use math inside a `proof`, you need e.g. `$...$` for inline math, or an `align` environment for multi-line math with alignment.

Comment: Please, don't post screen shots, rather paste your code.

Comment: @bmv I posted a screenshot rather than pasted the code because I wanted to show how TeX Studio was highlighting the syntax (to indicate that it didn't recognize it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not describing the problem correctly. When TeXstudio fails to recognize an environment, it is the `\begin` and `\end` that are highlighted red. For example if I add an environment `foo`, I get this:

[image: unrecognized env in TeXstudio]

The "unrecognized command" popup comes from hovering the mouse cursor over `\begin`. (Sorry, it didn't show up in screenshot.)

The problem you're facing is a different one: that you've used math mode-only code outside of math mode. The `proof` environment does *not* start math mode. And TeXstudio tells you that this is the case:

[image: TeXstudio: math command outside math env]

#### Additional note

I just saw that you're using `$$ ... $$` for displayed math. Don't do this, use `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` or `\[ .. \]` instead, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)